# Best method to to stream live video from Raspberry Pi to a React Native Expo app?

Tags: react-native, raspberry-pi, expo

I'm currently building an app that requires a live stream integration from a Raspberry Pi connected to a camera module into a React Native Expo Cli app. Since I'm particularly concerned about latency, I'm not sure what the best method is for streaming video. Currently I've found https://mux.com/ which would require setting up a server on the pi. Does anybody have any suggestions?